# Inserting data from one table(triplestore) to another(property table)

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, triplestore

I have a to transfer RDF data from a triplestore to property tables. Example of a triple store and a property table is given below.

**triplestore**

```
Subject Property Object
  Sub1 prop1 hello
  Sub2 prop1 hello1
  Sub3 prop1 hello2
  Sub1 prop2 world
  Sub2 prop2 world1
  Sub3 prop2 world2
  Sub4 prop3 random
```

**Property Table 1**

```
Subject prop1 prop2
Sub1    hello world
Sub2    hello1 world1
Sub3    hello2 world2
```

**Property Table 2**

```
Subject prop3
Sub4  random
```

This is a very simplified version of the dataset I am using. There are around a million records in the triplestore table. More than one property tables have to be created depending upon the various groupings of the various properties and objects. I have identified and created the various property tables? The properties that make a property table are  chosen in such a way that a subject is fully contained by a single property table?

The problem that I am facing is the insertion of data from the triplestore to the property tables. Is there a way that data for a particular subject can be inserted into a row of property table in a single insert statement.If it cant be done in a single query what is the most efficient way to do so.

I am using python to create a dump of SQL queries which I latter run on a postgres server.

Comment: SQLFiddle of sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/391b7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy if you have a known, fixed set of properties. If you do not have a known set of fixed properties you have to generate dynamic SQL, either from your app, from PL/PgSQL or using the `crosstab` function from the `tablefunc` extension.

For fixed property sets you can self-join:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/391b7/6

```
SELECT p1."Subject", p1."Object" AS "prop1", p2."Object" AS "prop2"
FROM triplestore p1
INNER JOIN triplestore p2 ON (p1."Subject" = p2."Subject")
WHERE p1."Property" = 'prop1'
  AND p2."Property" = 'prop2'
ORDER BY p1."Subject";

SELECT p1."Subject", p1."Object" AS "prop1"
FROM triplestore p1
WHERE p1."Property" = 'prop3'
ORDER BY p1."Subject";
```

To turn these into `INSERTs` simply use `INSERT ... SELECT` eg:

```
INSERT INTO "Property Table 1"
SELECT p1."Subject", p1."Object" AS "prop1"
FROM triplestore p1
WHERE p1."Property" = 'prop3'
ORDER BY p1."Subject";
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking what you try to do smells a bit of EAV (Entity Attribute Value) Pattern - which is widely considered an antipattern. In addition i think i don't really understand what you are trying to achieve therefor sorry if my answer doesn't suit your needs

If your problem is storing data of previously unknown format under a certain key - in your example this seem to be subject - i would suggest using the [postgres contrib hstore extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/hstore.html). Using this would allow you to create a table like

```
create table foo (
  id serial not null primary key,
  subject character varying not null,
  properties hstore
);
```

in which the properties field is essentially what Ruby for instance calls a "Hash". You can insert key/value pairs into this store (from your above example for instance 'prop1=>hello' and select it with equivalent syntax.

Inserting is fairly straight forward:

```
insert into foo (subject, properties) values ('Sub1', 'prop1=>Hello'::hstore);
```

Advantage over using other methods is that hstore supports btree, gin and gist indexes (all of which under certain preconditions). In your case - doing mostly direct matches searching for a certain value in a property even btree works since it support the equality operator for hstore.